# How to create subdomains automatically with Nginx ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

We're searching a way to use subdomains in a master-minion nginx ingress implementation. We've tried a lot of different approaches but we haven't got it. The documentation example works fine (https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/v1.8.1/examples/mergeable-ingress-types), but this example is with paths. Is there anyway to do it with subdomains or it's not possible?

I will have a different subdomain like the wordpress structure every time you create a new page, I would like to know what is the best way to do it.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you provide an example of the mappings you are trying to achieve? Ingress rules have a `host` property for the domain, does that cover your use case?

Answer (score 4):

The Nginx ingress controller documentation (https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/basic-usage/) got a pretty simple example working with different hosts:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-myservicea
  annotations:
    # use the shared ingress-nginx
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myservicea.foo.org
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: myservicea
          servicePort: 80
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-myserviceb
  annotations:
    # use the shared ingress-nginx
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myserviceb.foo.org
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: myserviceb
          servicePort: 80
```

What have you tried or trying to achieve that is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

@paltaa already showed one of the paths that you can choose, with 2 differents hosts.

---

As far as I understand by automatically you want a wildcard hosts, there is [github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/41881) about that.

[Kubernetes 1.18](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/04/02/improvements-to-the-ingress-api-in-kubernetes-1.18/) has been released with some enhancements, like wildcard in hostname and better handling of Path.

Quoted from kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#hostname-wildcards).

> Hosts can be precise matches (for example “foo.bar.com”) or a wildcard (for example “*.foo.com”). Precise matches require that the HTTP host header matches the host field. Wildcard matches require the HTTP host header is equal to the suffix of the wildcard rule.

```
Host        Host header       Match?    
*.foo.com   bar.foo.com       Matches based on shared suffix    
*.foo.com   baz.bar.foo.com   No match, wildcard only covers a single DNS label  
*.foo.com   foo.com No match, wildcard only covers a single DNS label
```

---

And there are 2 examples.

---

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-wildcard-host
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "foo.bar.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/bar"
        backend:
          service:
            name: service1
            port:
              number: 80
  - host: "*.foo.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/foo"
        backend:
          service:
            name: service2
            port:
              number: 80
```

---

```
apiVersion: "networking.k8s.io/v1beta1"
kind: "Ingress"
metadata:
  name: "example-ingress"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "*.example.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: "/example"
        pathType: "Prefix"
        backend:
          serviceName: "example-service"
          servicePort: 80
```